# How come my button appearance only changes when I hover over it after opening a new tab and coming back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jspdf

I press a button which generates a pdf for me through the jsPDF library. The problem is that the tab opens so fast I guess it messes with the visual effect of removeClass (when I come back to the page in Safari the button only visually lights up if I hover over it). The class I am removing is Bootstrap's disabled class. pdf.save is what is opening the new tab with my generated pdf file.

```
pdf.save('test.pdf');
$('#validate-codes-button').removeClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Is it the button that you clicked is the `$('#validate-codes-button')`? or it is different button?

Comment: @NelsonEstuestaJr it is a different button. I have a generate button and the validate button. When I press the generate button it generates the PDF in a different tab. When I come back the validate button is supposed to have disabled class removed, but that is what I am having a problem with.

Comment: It is probably to do something with the CSS of that button after the click event has been invoked. You can open a debugger and select that button using the DOM explorer functionality in debuggers, then you can see its CSS styles. It will help you see what is changing

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.

If you click the generate button you can trigger the validate button to disabled.

```
$("#generateBtn").on("click", function(){
   $('#validate-codes-button').removeClass('disabled');
```

});

Comment: That is how I have it except it is acting weird. It works as expected in Firefox but not Safari, I think because the new tab takes over.